# (raspberry pi 4 and Python) raspberry Camera mode raise picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError and picamera.exc.PiCameraError

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, picamera

system: raspberry pi 4 model B, use external usb logitech camera

**I'm follow the youtube tutorial but get `picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError` and`picamera.exc.PiCameraError`**

relate discussion on other site 2021 (I didn't get their solution): "Camera issue, no idea what the problem is"
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=324702

**- the python code:**

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time


print("= = = = = == = = = ")
camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(2)

camera.capture("test.jpg")
```

**- the whole output:**

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 456, in _init_camera
    self._camera = mo.MMALCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2279, in __init__
    super(MMALCamera, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 631, in __init__
    mmal_check(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.ril.camera': Out of memory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/Desktop/camera.py", line 6, in <module>
    camera = PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 431, in __init__
    self._init_camera(camera_num, stereo_mode, stereo_decimate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 459, in _init_camera
    raise PiCameraError(
picamera.exc.PiCameraError: Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
```

---

- the youtube tutorial I follow:

How to Take Photos and Videos with Raspberry Pi Camera Module
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx8gDSS1vO4&list=PLnjnmu-sbNYMvMiXd-y5t7fYts1N0hmuI&index=3&t=331s&ab_channel=TechWithTim

- troubleshooting:
  (`Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.`
  --> the follow picture I just make sure the camera is enable, maybe because I used external usb logitech camera )

https://ibb.co/Jyxtbfv
https://ibb.co/CHrWRH1

I'm the python beginner, and first day have raspberry pi, stocking on camera setup, how can I fix this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable `Pi-camera` in setting.That's what error is saying.

1. Type `sudo raspi-config` in terminal & hit enter.
2. Go to `interface options`
3. Go to `p1 Legacy camera` and hit enetr After enable it.

4.Reboot

[image]

As you mentioned external camera What happens here I guess is raspberry Pi has onboard camera socket. WHen we conncet camera to it Raspberry pi assigns as device id =0 internally. When we connect second camera(which is through USB yourcase). It will be assigned witj device id =1 ...As you not mentioned which device Id it deafultly checking at devic id=0 which not exists. Let me check documention how to re assign Id. I Know how to do that opencv but, Never tried in this pi camera module. in meanwhile try `opencv`

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

After installation of library

```
import cv2
  
  
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1) ########## 1- device id =1###if 1 deosn't work try 2
  
while(True):
      
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()
  
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      
    # the 'q' button is set as the
    # quitting button you may use any
    # desired button of your choice
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
  
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: hi thanks for made a nice and clear short video for me but after I reboot it, still face the same issue (with same error code)

Comment: Edited meanwhile try `open-cv`

Comment: it download the whole night, download failed but I think is the right track 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/python/cv2/config-3.py'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-contrib-python
Failed to build opencv-contrib-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-contrib-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly' , I will keep on doing this

Comment: Ahh just `Google it`...How to install `open-cv` in `raspberry Pi` though `pip` python...I guess you must need `open-cv` for your future projects...